# Getting cursor content

Tags: android, android-cursor

i'm trying to get the content of a cursor but i only have one value out of the 2 encased in the cursor

this is my code

```
public List<Countries> getAllCountries() {
    List<Countries> country = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + BDD.TABLE_COUNTRIES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Countries c = new Countries();
            c.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.NAME_COUNTRY)));
            c.setCode(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.CODE)));


            country.add(c);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // close db connection
    db.close();

    // return notes list
    return country;
}
```

i can only get this line `c.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.NAME_COUNTRY)));

i tried inverting the line but it does'nt change 
this is the code to get the cursor content

```
final ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    //Création d'un livre
   final Countries country = new Countries("Cameroun", 232);

    ajout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){

            //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
            DbM.open();
            //On insère le livre que l'on vient de créer
            DbM.addCountry(country);

            int countryFromBdd = DbM.getNumber();
            List<Countries> values = DbM.getAllCountries();

            if(countryFromBdd != 0){

                final ArrayAdapter<Countries> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Countries>(CountryDataBaseManagement.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    });
```

i don't know how to get this line  to show it in the listview `c.setCode(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.CODE)));

thank you for your help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need getColumnIndex. You can use Cursor with an index like 0, 1, 2 etc.

Try to change:

```
        Countries c = new Countries();
        c.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.NAME_COUNTRY)));
        c.setCode(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BDD.CODE)));
```

to

```
        Countries c = new Countries();
        c.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        c.setCode(cursor.getInt(1));
```

if your columns are the same order.

Comment: Hello, i tried it, it works but it only show one column at a time in the listview, isn't it possible to get and show the 2 column at the same time ?

Comment: it is possible, just use custom listview.

Comment: Thanks for your help